# Is there a way to efficiently construct a 3d array from symmetric submatrices of a 2d array according to an array of different index sets?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a two-dimensional array `A`, and another two-dimensional array `I` where each row corresponds to a set of indices with which I want to extract symmetric two-dimensional subarrays from `A`. I want to collect all of these submatrices into a three-dimensional array without resorting to for loops.

e.g.

```
I = Array([[  0,   1,   0],
           [  0,   1,   1],
           [  0,   1,   2],
            ...,
           [  0,   1, 997],
           [  0,   1, 998],
           [  0,   1, 999]], dtype=int32)
```

So, the first submatrix of A would be the symmetric 3x3 subarray `A[[0, 1, 0], :][:, [0, 1, 0]]`. Now, I want to define a three-dimensional array B, where we have `B[0, :, :] = A[I[0, :], :][:, I[0, :]]`, `B[1, :, :] = A[I[1, :], :][:, I[1, :]]` etc.

I currently have the following code

```
import numpy as np

A = A = np.random.rand(1000,1000)

current_idxs = np.arange(2)
possible_next_idxs = np.arange(1000)
I = np.hstack(( np.tile( current_idxs, (possible_next_idxs.shape[0], 1) ), possible_next_idxs ))
```

Then a simple but slow solution is

```
B = np.array([A[idx, :][:, idx] for idx in I ])
```

This gives me the result I need but is very slow, there must be a way to do what I want in a vectorised fashion but I am not sure how. It seems like `np.take_along_axis` might be the answer but nothing I have tried works. Any help would be appreciated as constructing this matrix of submatrices is a big bottleneck in my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some indexing tricks!

```
B = A[ I[:, :, None], I[:, None, :] ]
```

Verifying:

```
>>> np.array_equal(
...     A[ I[:, :, None], I[:, None, :] ],
...     np.array([A[idx, :][:, idx] for idx in I ])
... )
True
```